# Installing apps on my own device through Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I’m quite new to Xcode and I’m only interested in making apps as a hobby. I would like to install my own apps that I make on my own devices without using the App Store (without paying the £99/year developer fee). So I would like to know the following:

1. How can I install an app through Xcode so that the app remains on my iPhone after disconnecting it from my Mac?
2. How long will the app remain on my iPhone i.e. how long until I have to manually reinstall it? (I’ve seen some websites that say 7 days and some that say 1 year)
3. This is something else really but am I right in thinking to use the TestFlight app I’d need to pay the £99/year developer fee?

If it helps all my devices are running the latest software versions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes, you can use your own device for testing purposes and it will remain on your phone after you disconnect it.

To set this up, connect your device to your Mac. Then, click the simulator selection dropdown in the top left of Xcode. It might say `Generic iOS Device` if you haven't selected a simulator since opening Xcode. At the bottom of that dropdown menu, you should see a button that says `Add additional simulators...`

At the top of the window that comes up after you click `Add additional simulators..` there should be a `Devices` tab. Select that tab and add your device via the `+` icon in the bottom left of the window. Once connected and paired, you can travel back to the simulator dropdown menu and scroll up. Your device should be listed there if it's plugged in and paired. Select the device and run your app - Xcode will take care of installation.

2. Without purchasing the `Apple Developer Program`, your app will function on your phone for one week after the most recent run.
3. Yes, you are correct. `TestFlight` is something that comes with the `Apple Developer Program`.